# react load svg image from url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I am loading an svg image from a url passed in via the `src` prop.

The trouble I'm having is that I am storing the svg into state but when the url changes the image displayed will be the previous image clicked and not the current image

I can see that the image stored in state is always the last image selected

I believe it is how it is fetching the image from the api and storing it in to state here but I don't quite understand how this works and how it updates the state with the svg

```
).then(
   svg => this.state.image = svg
);
```

How can I change this so that state updates with the correct image?

**SVG Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import $ from 'jquery';

class InlineSVG extends React.Component {
  state = {
    image: '',
  };


  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    this.loadSVG();
  }


  loadSVG() {
      fetch(this.props.src)
        .then(
          response => {
            if (!response.ok) return Promise.reject(new Error('Server 
Error'));
            return response.text();
          }
        ).then(
          svg => this.state.image = svg
        );
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.image}} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default InlineSVG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mutate state directly. You are mutating state directly and that’s why you don’t see the Updated image. When you mutate the state directly your component won’t re-render and that’s why updated image isn’t shown

Wrong

```
).then(
    svg => this.state.image = svg);
```

Right

```
 ).then(
    svg => this.setState({ image:  svg});
```

PS:- to modify React state value you need to use setState so that your component will re render with the updated data

Comment: this works but because it's used in the ComponentDidUpdate it constantly loops, how can I prevent this?

Comment: I added a check to see if the src was different to the previous src `prevProps.src !== this.props.src && this.loadSVG()` now works :)

Comment: Cool enjoy playing with React :)