# React Import SVG inline from URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I am working on an issue where SVG image needs to be loaded from URL(AWS S3) to a react component. I am able to successfully show and load image using the SVG-inline react component from a local file. However, the svg files needs to be loaded inline from S3 bucket, JS svg import does not work with URLs.

So I am trying to find the best alternative solution for this?

Comment: Unsure what you mean... If the image is visible on the net, you should be able to add it in the image tag, right? It's just like any other html document. Or is it an issue when/if compiling?

Comment: To import the SVG inline as a React component from URL, I manage to load the SVG from local file inline, but not from URL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react load svg image from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52519270/react-load-svg-image-from-url)

Answer (score 19):

[@ivnkld answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52967417/1872494) pointed me to the right direction, thanks! And for Googlers such as I was, here is implementation of the same approach with hooks:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const SvgInline = props => {
    const [svg, setSvg] = useState(null);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [isErrored, setIsErrored] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(props.url)
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(setSvg)
            .catch(setIsErrored)
            .then(() => setIsLoaded(true))
    }, [props.url]);

    return (
        <div 
            className={`svgInline svgInline--${isLoaded ? 'loaded' : 'loading'} ${isErrored ? 'svgInline--errored' : ''}`}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: svg }}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You should fetch svg image and paste it in html

```
const SVG_URL = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/106114/tiger.svg';

class Svg extends React.Component {
  state = {
    svg: null,
    loading: false,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.props.url)
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(text => this.setState({ svg: text }));
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, svg } = this.state;
    if (loading) {
      return <div className="spinner"/>;
    } else if(!svg) {
      return <div className="error"/>
    }
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.svg}}/>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Svg url='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/106114/tiger.svg' />,
  document.querySelector("#app")
);
```

you can can edit example here https://jsfiddle.net/anu6x3bk/

React does not recommend using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` so you should use some package like `svg-inline-react`

Comment: No need for external package since `svg-inline-react` also use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`: https://github.com/sairion/svg-inline-react/blob/master/src/index.js

Answer (score 4):

For those who want to avoid using *dangerouslySetInnerHTML* please check the following example. Once we get the svg as text from the api, we will use **DOMParser** to convert the text to **Document** object. We will then use **React.createElement** to render the image (or) icon.

```js
// utils/convertDocEleToReact.js
import { createElement } from "react";

const innerFunction = (element, props) => {
    const tagName = element.tagName;
    let _props = props || {};

    for(let i = 0; i < element.attributes.length; i++){
      _props[element.attributes[i].nodeName] = element.attributes[i].nodeValue;
    }

    let children = Array.from(element.children).map(item => innerFunction(item));

    return createElement(tagName, _props, children);
};

export const convertDocEleToReact = (element, props) => {
    try{
       return innerFunction(element, props);
    }
    catch(ex){
      return createElement("span", {}, "Error loading svg image");
    }
};
```

```
// components/SVGUrl.js
import React from "react";
import { convertDocEleToReact } from "./utils/convertDocEleToReact";

export const SVGUrl = ({ ...props }) => {
    const [ Comp, setComp ] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(_ => {
        setLoading(true);
        fetch(/** svg url */)
          .then(res => res.text())
          .then(res => {
              const domParser = new DOMParser();
              const ele = domParser.parseFromString(res, "image/svg+xml");
              setComp(convertDocEleToReact(ele.documentElement, props));
              setLoading(false);
          });
    }, []);

    return loading ? "..." : Comp;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Now `React` support `SVG` just use `<img/>` tag, something like below.

```
<img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/106114/tiger.svg' />
```

Comment: Please specify from what version of React they support this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @petr-cibulka's answer I looked into not having the need for a wrapper around the svg tag.

Here's a slightly modified version of what I found online.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export const SvgInline = ({ url }: { url: string }) => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLImageElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      const data = await fetch(url);
      const svgHtml = await data.text();

      if (ref.current) {
        ref.current.outerHTML = svgHtml;
      }
    })();
  }, [url]);

  return <img ref={ref} src={url} alt="" />;
};
```

The benefit is that if it fails for some reason, you still have an `img` rendering the `svg`.

The drawback is that you have to make sure the `img` and `svg` are styled and sized the same otherwise it'll have a weird flickering effect. If you're looking to color the `svg`, this will make a weird color shift since you can't do it on the `img` tag... But it could be anything, doesn't have to be an `img` tag.