# How to dynamically import SVG and render it inline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I have a function that takes some arguments and renders an SVG. I want to dynamically import that svg based on the name passed to the function. It looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

export default async ({name, size = 16, color = '#000'}) => {
  const Icon = await import(/* webpackMode: "eager" */ `./icons/${name}.svg`);
  return <Icon width={size} height={size} fill={color} />;
};
```

According to the [webpack documentation for dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments) and the magic comment "eager":

> "Generates no extra chunk. All modules are included in the current
> chunk and no additional network requests are made. A Promise is still
> returned but is already resolved. In contrast to a static import, the
> module isn't executed until the call to import() is made."

This is what my Icon is resolved to:

```
> Module
default: "static/media/antenna.11b95602.svg"
__esModule: true
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
```

Trying to render it the way my function is trying to gives me this error:

`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

I don't understand how to use this imported Module to render it as a component, or is it even possible this way?

Comment: Does your svg display correctly if you statically import?

Comment: Yes! If I do a regular `import MyIcon from './icons/myicon.svg'` I can render it like `<MyIcon />`.

Comment: You might have to store the resolved SVG in a state instead.

Comment: @dev_junwen Correct, but storing it in state still doesn't enable me to render it as an inline svg.

Comment: Or another rather "dynamic" way is maybe you can define a map of name to SVG components, then use the bracket notation syntax `iconMap[name]` to retrieve the correct SVG. I haven't tested it yet but I think that could work. You will need to import all SVG in that case and assign it to the map.

Comment: @dev_junwen Yes, that's how I first did it. Problem is, you would have to manually import all icons as `import CarIcon from 'car.svg'` etc, then map as `{car: CarIcon}`, then you can render them inline like `const Icon = nameToIcon[name]; <Icon />`. But it doesn't solve the problem of dynamically importing all the SVGs.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

### Next.js (SSR)

If you are using a modern React framework like [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) that supports SSR, dynamically importing SVG is very easy. The following guide demonstrates the concept, which should be applicable for any other frameworks that support SSR.

Assuming SVG files are placed in assets folder:

```bash
├── src
│   └── assets
│       ├── a-b-2.svg
│       └── a-b-off.svg
```

1. Install [`@svgr/webpack`](https://react-svgr.com/docs/next/) (or any other SVG loader of your choice), which allow you to import SVG files directly and use them as React components. *Feel free to skip this step if you already have a loader in place.
2. Add a `src/components/lazy-svg.tsx` async component.

   ```
   import { ComponentProps } from "react";

   import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

   interface LazySvgProps extends ComponentProps<"svg"> {
     name: string;
   }

   export const LazySvg = async ({ name, ...props }: LazySvgProps) => {
     const Svg = dynamic(() => import(`@/assets/${name}.svg`));

     // Or without using `dynamic`:
     // We use `default` here because `@svgr/webpack` converts all other *.svg imports to React components, this might be different for other loaders.
     // const Svg = (await import(`@/assets/${name}.svg`)).default;

     return <Svg {...props} />;
   };
   ```
3. Import and use it as follows:

   ```
   import { LazySvg } from "@/components/lazy-svg";

   // Server side:
   <LazySvg name="a-b-2" />

   // Client side: Wrap with Suspense to render loading state when SVG is loading.
   <Suspense fallback={<>Loading...</>}>
     <LazySvg name="a-b-2" />
   </Suspense>
   ```

#### Usages

##### Server Demo

```
import { LazySvg } from "@/components/lazy-svg";

export const ServerDemo = () => (
  <div>
    <LazySvg name="a-b-2" stroke="yellow" />
    <LazySvg name="a-b-off" stroke="lightgreen" />
  </div>
);
```

##### Client Demo

```
"use client";

import { Suspense, useState } from "react";
import { LazySvg } from "@/components/lazy-svg";

export const ClientDemo = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState<"a-b-2" | "a-b-off">("a-b-2");

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setName((prevName) => (prevName === "a-b-2" ? "a-b-off" : "a-b-2"))
        }
      >
        Change Icon
      </button>
      <Suspense fallback={<>Loading...</>}>
        <LazySvg
          name={name}
          stroke={name === "a-b-2" ? "yellow" : "lightgreen"}
        />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit nextjs-dynamic-svg-import]

### Vite React (SPA)

If you are not using SSR, you can dynamically import SVG files using the dynamic import hook. The following guide demonstrates the concept, which should be applicable for any other frameworks that use SPA.

Assuming SVG files are placed in assets folder:

```bash
├── src
│   └── assets
│       ├── a-b-2.svg
│       └── a-b-off.svg
```

1. Install [`vite-plugin-svgr`](https://github.com/pd4d10/vite-plugin-svgr) (or any other SVG loader of your choice), which allow you to import SVG files directly and use them as React components. *Feel free to skip this step if you already have a loader in place.
2. Add a `src/components/lazy-svg.tsx` component.

   ```
   import { ComponentProps, FC, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

   interface LazySvgProps extends ComponentProps<"svg"> {
     name: string;
   }

   // This hook can be used to create your own wrapper component.
   const useLazySvgImport = (name: string) => {
     const importRef = useRef<FC<ComponentProps<"svg">>>();
     const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
     const [error, setError] = useState<Error>();

     useEffect(() => {
       setLoading(true);
       const importIcon = async (): Promise<void> => {
         try {
           importRef.current = (
             await import(`../assets/${name}.svg?react`)
           ).default; // We use `?react` here following `vite-plugin-svgr`'s convention.
         } catch (err) {
           setError(err as Error);
         } finally {
           setLoading(false);
         }
       };
       importIcon();
     }, [name]);

     return {
       error,
       loading,
       Svg: importRef.current,
     };
   };

   // Example wrapper component using the hook.
   export const LazySvg = ({ name, ...props }: LazySvgProps) => {
     const { loading, error, Svg } = useLazySvgImport(name);

     if (error) {
       return "An error occurred";
     }

     if (loading) {
       return "Loading...";
     }

     if (!Svg) {
       return null;
     }

     return <Svg {...props} />;
   };
   ```

#### Usage

```
import { useState } from "react";

import { LazySvg } from "./components/lazy-svg";

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState<"a-b-2" | "a-b-off">("a-b-2");

  return (
    <main>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setName((prevName) => (prevName === "a-b-2" ? "a-b-off" : "a-b-2"))
        }
      >
        Change Icon
      </button>
      <LazySvg
        name={name}
        stroke={name === "a-b-2" ? "yellow" : "lightgreen"}
      />
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: Edit vite-react-ts-dynamic-svg-import]

### Create React App (SPA) [*Deprecated*]

The majority of Vite's guide applies, with the only difference being on the `import` method:

```
const useLazySvgImport = (name: string) => {
  const importRef = useRef<FC<ComponentProps<"svg">>>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<Error>();

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const importIcon = async (): Promise<void> => {
      try {
        importRef.current = (
          await import(`../assets/${name}.svg`)
        ).ReactComponent; // CRA comes pre-configured with SVG loader, see https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs.
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err as Error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    importIcon();
  }, [name]);

  return {
    error,
    loading,
    Svg: importRef.current,
  };
};
```

### Caveats

There’s limitation when using dynamic imports with variable parts. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54257036/11125492) explained the issue in detail.

To workaround with this, you can make the dynamic import path to be more explicit.

E.g, Instead of

```
<LazySvg path="../../assets/icon.svg" />;

// ...

import(path);
```

You can change it to

```
<LazySvg name="icon" />;

// ...

import(`../../icons/${name}.svg`);
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you, very clean! I had completely missed the ReactComponent in any documentation. I would think it would show up as a public method on the imported object when inspected, imho, but I guess that's not how things work here. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Btw @dev_junwen ReactComponent never worked for me, I have no idea how this code works in your CodeSandbox, but `.ReactComponent` just returns undefined for me. I hade to change it and use `.default` as in @Enchew's example below. I found some great documentation on this here if you go down to "Importing defaults": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: What React version are you using? The sandbox example should be the latest. You can try `import { ReactComponent as Icon } from 'SVG_PATH.svg';` and see if it resolves to the SVG html

Comment: Fantastic use of `ref`! How would this look in Typescript?

Comment: @Willege I've updated the answer. Feel free to take a look at the code sample.

Comment: @dev_junwen Unfortunately this solution doesn't work me. I've tried everything. Even if I download the code from CodeSandbox and install all dependencies from scratch with `npm install`, the SVG images are not loaded. I also don't get an error message. Is there something I'm doing wrong (maybe webpack, babel or typescript configuration)?

Comment: @mamiu Are you using Create React App ? If not you will need to setup inline svg loader manually. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61713646/11125492) answer might help.

Comment: @dev_junwen Thanks for your quick response! I tried it with and without CRA. But still not working. I'm following error in the console, but I think it's unrelated: `Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.`
I tried it first in my main react project, which is not using CRA, but now I created multiple plain react projects (with and without CRA, with yarn and with npm) and have no clue why it's not working.

Comment: @mamiu Is there a way I can inspect your project code (setup) ? Or maybe a very simple project that you've tested but doesn't work. There are many possibilities why it doesn't work so Its hard for me to debug without looking at some source codes. Make sure your project actually includes SVG files for you to import and test.

Comment: @dev_junwen this solution doesn't work for me either. It resolves correctly when I import statically like `import { ReactComponent as Icon } from 'SVG_PATH.svg'`, but the dynamic import like in your answer gets ignored by webpack for some reason. I'm on React 16.3.1 and React-scripts 3.4.1

Comment: @Salet It appears to be a webpack config bug as described [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5276). There are no solutions for now unfortunately.

Comment: I'm using CRA and am getting this error

```index.tsx:134 Uncaught (in promise) Error: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 28 failed.```

Does anyone have any insight into what could be causing this?

Comment: dynamic import not working for me. I get `Cannot find module '.../path/to/file.svg'` . However direct import works `import {ReactComponent as Icon} from '../path/to/file.svg'`. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: @surjit I think you accidentally wrote triple dots `.../` instead of `../`.

Comment: @junwen-k sorry for the typing mistake while commenting.. but in my code I have `../`

Comment: @junwen-k This is the exact error `index.js:1 Error: Cannot find module '../assets/images/sideNav/overview.svg'`

Comment: @Mark Does restarting your React app helped? Hard to tell with just that error code.

Comment: @junwen-k I tried restarting the app. No effect 

Comment: @junwen-k I'm using Create-react-app typescript: 4.2.2, react: 17.0.1. Do you think it might be anything related to webpack??

Comment: @surjit I've updated the answer with your current case, hopefully that helps.

Comment: @junwen-k Yes its working . giving your answer an up vote.

Comment: Can I use your code for personal and commercial projects ?

Comment: I have a `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.` if the parent component re-renders before icons finished loading. Any hint on this? Can't those be cancelled?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger Is it possible to provide a minimal reproducible sandbox? Perhaps you can wrap the SVG fetch method as a promise and reject the promise immediately on unmount.

Comment: Yup, I did this: `let isActive = true; if (isActive) {setLoading(false);} return () => {isActive = false;}` (sorry for ugly formatting). Maybe this is worth updating your answer.

Comment: I get a completely different error: `Cannot read property 'dispose' of undefined`

Comment: Please help, for me it always logs "svgname.svg successfully loaded", but nothing is displayed, no error message at all. I'm using exactly your code from codesandbox.io. I forked it and updated to react/ react-dom 17.0.2. It's working fine on codesandbox, but not in my current project, which uses webpack. I've tried everything and it should definitely work. The problem is not the svg file itself. I uploaded mine to codesandbox and it works. I even created a new local project with create-react-app. Still, "successfully loaded", no error, but svg is not displayed.

Comment: @junwen-k directly downloaded your codesandbox files. Same issue. npm --version 7.20.6 , node --version v14.16.0. I don't get it.

Comment: @Nulldroid Does following this solution helps? https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5276#issuecomment-665628393 Could be related to webpack importing issue. Also at which part did you log the "successfully loaded" message?

Comment: Thank you so much! Your link led me into the right direction. I fixed it now using @svgr/webpack inline loading and excluding inline svg from font file loader in my current project.

Comment: Where should I look for solution if I'm getting error: "ERROR Error: Cannot find module 'undefined' at webpackMissingModule" ?

Comment: Would this work if I get .svg file from a service? For example, we have hundreds of SVG files that we need to render inline. But the time webpack runs, none of these SVG files are present in the soure code. Does anyone know how to approach this?

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov Hi, maybe your can look through this question, might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52964997/react-import-svg-inline-from-url

Comment: It doesn't work with the latest CRA (react-scripts v5). I have been trying to figure out the changes in the new Webpack v5 config of CRA but can't seem to get it to work so far or fully understand the issue.

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/static/media/xyz.65482ff5b931f5ffc8ab.svg') is not a valid name.`

Comment: @Indigo Hi, make sure you are importing `ReactComponent` instead of the default export ```import { ReactComponent as ... } from 'SVG_PATH';```

Comment: @junwen-k the question is about dynamic import

Comment: @Indigo Yes, what I meant was when you use import(...), make sure it is taking the ReactComponent like ```ImportedIconRef.current = (await  import(`./${name}.svg`)).ReactComponent;``` It seems like your import statement resolved to a `src` which you usually put into an `<img />` tag. I've tested using the latest CRA and seem to have no issue. Care to provide a minimal reproducible sandbox?

Comment: If it's not working try to configure webpack with `@svgr` like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70961634/3319170

Comment: For anyone still getting `undefined`, there is a bug for dynamic webpack loading when the "issuer" property is set for svgs (https://github.com/webpack/webpack/discussions/15117#discussioncomment-1925385). The fix is removing the "issurer" config from the svg loader in the webpack config. Since we are using create-react-app, and haven't ejected, we utilized `patch-package` to remove those lines from the webpack config, and now everything is working.

Comment: @JordanSoltman: can you share how you remove those line using `patch-package`?
@junwen-k: I am getting the same error as @Indigo but I am uing `react-scripts v4.0.3`

Comment: @b-asaf You can comment those lines by your self. They're located in `./node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`

Comment: @SaberHayati - tried installing `@svgr` based on this comment - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175445/cant-import-svg-into-next-js/70961634#70961634 but with no luck :(

Comment: I keep getting the error: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/static/media/icons8-team.7d336a6dcad1b0b4df3e.svg') is not a valid name. I tried using "ReactComponent" as the import, but then I am getting undefined and the icon is not showing. So it seems I have to use the "default" any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Yousi By any chance that you are using Vite? You may take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70685179/11125492 and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @junwen-k for your reply. But I am not use Vite. But I noticed something, when I type the path of the icon manually (without using the template literal) it works fine and I can see the SVG icon. It seems that webpack doesn't like variables

Comment: All this effort ... and not a single usage example?

Comment: @machineghost Thank you for reminding me; I've been wanting to update this answer for a long time. I've rewritten it with a detailed explanation and examples. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 15):

Your rendering functions (for class components) and function components should not be async (because they must return DOMNode or null - in your case, they return a Promise). Instead, you could render them in the regular way, after that import the icon and use it in the next render. Try the following:

```
const Test = () => {
  let [icon, setIcon] = useState('');

  useEffect(async () => {
    let importedIcon = await import('your_path');
    setIcon(importedIcon.default);
  }, []);

  return <img alt='' src={ icon }/>;
};
```

Comment: This probably works for an img tag where the source will be importedIcon.default, as you wrote, but it doesn't work in my case with an inline svg, where I want to render it as <Icon />. I tried your approach with an async useEffect, but then I need to `setIcon` with the whole Module, not importedIcon.default (the file path), then rendering it like <Icon />, and it gives me the error `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

Comment: Why do you need to render it as an `<Icon>` ? What does this approach give you and is there any difference, that can't be overcome by using `<img>`

Comment: How would I then change the properties of the svg if it's a img tag, like the fill color of the icon? Is it possible with an img tag?

Comment: Effects can't host an `async` function. They return a promise which gets invoked as a cleanup function. https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data

Comment: Regardless of what the original question is, this probably is the best answer for "dynamically import local files". This works well when I have a list of file URLs and load dynamically.

Comment: Not working for me, I'm using craco, how to override webpack configuration ?

Answer (score 5):

I made a change based on answer https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5276#issuecomment-665628393

```
export const Icon: FC<IconProps> = ({ name, ...rest }): JSX.Element | null => {
      const ImportedIconRef = useRef<FC<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>> | any>();
      const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
      useEffect((): void => {
        setLoading(true);
        const importIcon = async (): Promise<void> => {
          try {
            // Changing this line works fine to me
            ImportedIconRef.current = (await import(`!!@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+titleProp,+ref!./${name}.svg`)).default;
          } catch (err) {
            throw err;
          } finally {
            setLoading(false);
          }
        };
        importIcon();
      }, [name]);

      if (!loading && ImportedIconRef.current) {
        const { current: ImportedIcon } = ImportedIconRef;
        return <ImportedIcon {...rest} />;
      }
      return null;
    };
```

Comment: Thanks @kraken711 for your insight. When I try your approach I am getting an error: `Module not found: Can't resolve @svgr/webpack?-svgo,+titleProp,+ref!.`
I tried :
1. `await import(!!@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+titleProp,+ref!./[path_to_icon_folder]/${name}.svg))`
2. `await import(!!@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+titleProp,+ref!./${name}.svg))`

Answer (score 2):

One solution to load the svg dynamically could be to load it inside an **img** using *require*, example:

```
<img src={require(`../assets/${logoNameVariable}`)?.default} />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use lazy/suspence

```
import { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';

const Icon = ({name}) => {
  const LazyIcon = lazy(() => {
    return import(`./icons/${name}.svg`);
  });

  return (
    <Suspense>
      <LazyIcon />
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

i changed my code to this and work:

`import { ReactComponent as Dog } from './Dog.svg';`

use like this:

```
<Dog />
```

or if it is dynamic:

```
 import * as icons from '../../assets/categoryIcons';

 const IconComponent = icons[componentName??'Dog'];

 <IconComponent fill='red' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, even if I like the initial one

Available for React version 16.6.0 and greater, I used the lazy function and Suspense to dynamically load my sprites.

```
const IconSprites = React.lazy(async () => {
   return { default: (await import(`sprites/.svg`)).ReactComponent }
})
```

And

```
export default function App(): JSX.Element {
  ...
  return (
   <Suspense>
    <IconSprites style={{ display: 'none' }} />
   </Suspense>
   ...
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Quote @junwen-k's answer, if you are using the latest vite, and react18+, you need to rewrite it like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5f7j.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78084683/11107541

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35714653)

Answer (score -2):

I dynamically fetched the SVG file as text and then put the SVG within a div `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```
  const Icon = ({ className, name, size = 16 }: IconProps) => {
  const [Icon, setIcon] = React.useState("");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/icons/${name}.svg`)
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.startsWith("<svg")) return setIcon(res);
        console.error(
          `Icon: "${name}.svg" not found in ${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/icons`
        );
        return setIcon("");
      });
  }, [name]);

  if (!Icon) return null;

  return (
    <div
      className={classNames("icon", className)}
      style={{ width: !size ? "100%" : size + "px", height: "100%" }}
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: Icon }}
    />
  );
};
```

[Preview on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ts-dynamic-icon-comoponent-lq806v)

You can automatically change the color of your svg by giving it a fill value of "currentColor".