# How to dynamically import SVG from a web service and render it inline

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, create-react-app, inline

We have hundreds of SVG files that I am trying to render inline. I am using create-react-app which already has @svgr/webpack installed and configured. It allows me to add SVG inline like so:

```
import { ReactComponent as SvgImage } from '../Plans/Brownlow-Floor-Plan.svg';
...

<SvgImage style={{ width: "600px !important" }} />
```

[image]

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339259/how-to-dynamically-import-svg-and-render-it-inline) provides a solution for dynamically rendering SVG inline. However, In *my* case, I don't have any SVG files in the source code. Instead, all SVG files are returned to me via a call to an API service. For example:

- http://myservice/api/getplan(100)
- http://myservice/api/getplan(103)
- http://myservice/api/getplan(106)
- http://myservice/api/getplan(631)

As a result, by the time webpack is run, it has no information about these SVG files.

So my question is: is it possible to render svg dynamically in react (TypeScript) if I pull SVG file from an external URL?

This is not a duplicate question:
[How to dynamically import SVG and render it inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339259/how-to-dynamically-import-svg-and-render-it-inline)

Approach described in the question above is not going to work because it expects all SVG files to be added to the source code.

This approach also not going to work because simply using an img tag will not pull SVG inline:

```
<img src="plan.svg" />
```

[image]

Including SVG via an img tag make these kinds of things impossible:
[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is this your answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61339259/12232340

Comment: @Dlk, thank you, but I specifically mentioned this post in my question and explained that it's no the same question. The solution provided in that post does not apply to my case. I explain the reasons in my question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an excellent package called [`react-svg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg) that does exactly what you want.

You can use it with a simple `src` property that takes a url string, just like an `<img>` tag. But behind the scenes, it will download the svg file from the url and inject it inline. For example:

```
import { ReactSVG } from 'react-svg'

Component = () => <ReactSVG src="http://somewhere.com/my.svg" />,
```

Comment: thank you very much! this is an amazing component. Exactly what I was looking for. I was already considering using using dangerouslySetInnerHTML to to set SVG this way, but ReactSVG is much better!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work for you but, you can try to using the tag `<use />` within an `<svg />` tag. For example:

```
<svg
    height={iconHeight}
    viewBox={`0 0 ${iconWidth} ${iconHeight}`}
    width={iconWidth}
>
    <use xlinkHref={`${svgPath}#${icon}`} />
</svg>
```

Where `svgPath` is the URL to the SVG, and `icon` is an ID set on the SVG. You can try to omit to the `#${icon}` portion.

Not sure if this helps though.

If you choose this route, you may be incompatible with IE... For that you can use [svg4everybody](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody), but tbh IE is dead and it should stay dead.

Cheers!