# Dynamic SVG import in Preact + Vite

Tags: svg, vite, preact

I am trying to set up dynamic svg imports since my app uses many icons and I don't want to impact startup time to load all icons i.e. load them ***only*** when used.

I have been following other SO questions and implemented something similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61472427/7323010) in a React + Webpack project.

I am trying to implement the same hook in ***Preact + Vite***:

***dynamic import hook***

```js
import { FunctionComponent } from 'preact';
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'preact/hooks';

type Props = {
  name: string;
};

export const useDynamicSVGImport = ({ name }: Props) => {
  const ImportedIconRef = useRef<
    FunctionComponent<SVGSVGElement> | undefined
  >();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<Error>();

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);

    const importIcon = async (): Promise<void> => {
      try {
        const imported = await import(`../../assets/icons/${name}.svg`).then(
          module => module.default,
        );

        // logs: /src/assets/icons/spinner.svg if I pass name = spinner
        console.log('imported', imported); 

        ImportedIconRef.current = imported;
        
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);

        setError(err);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    importIcon();
  }, [name]);

  return {
    loading,
    error,
    SvgIcon: ImportedIconRef.current,
  };
};
```

Note: If I pass `SvgIcon` to the `src` of an `img` tag it renders the icon properly so it is being imported.

***icon.tsx***

```js
import { FunctionComponent } from 'preact';

import { useDynamicSVGImport } from '~/hooks/icons/use-dynamic-import';

type Props = {
  name: string;
  className?: string;
  isOutlineIcon?: boolean;
};

export const Icon: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  name,
  className,
  isOutlineIcon = false,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  const { error, loading, SvgIcon } = useDynamicSVGImport({ name });

  if (error || !SvgIcon || loading) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <SvgIcon
      className={`
        fill-slate-400
        ${isOutlineIcon ? '' : 'fill-current'}
        ${className ? className : 'h-5 w-5 text-lightBlack'}`}
      {...restProps}
    />
  );
};
```

When I render my `<Icon name="spinner" />` I get the following error:

```bash
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document':

The tag name provided ('/src/assets/icons/spinner.svg') is not a valid name.
```

What am I missing to properly render my `svg` component?

Comment: Probably not what you want (are you paid by LOC?) but you can do it [in 8 lines of Native JavaScript](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman that's pretty neat but I'd like a Preact solution though. Thanks!

Comment: LOL, That is what I said, you want more LOC

Comment: Idk what LOC means 

Comment: _Lines Of Code_, in the olden days us contractors would get paid by the number of lines of code we wrote in a day. And then the Frameworks got popular, and companies had to come up with a different metric.

Comment: Ah okay - if more LOC means staying consistent then sure.

Comment: Isn't the svg file just an image? Can't you just do `<img src={'assets/icons/' + name + '.svg'}/>`?

Comment: @MattNienow yeah I can but then I am unable to pass props