# Get Id clicked on a svg in JavaScript/React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg, event-handling

I have a dynamic svg which had a data-id in it's path. I want to find out the id of the path clicked in the svg.

sample svg -

```
<svg width="208" height="94" viewBox="0 0 208 94" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path data-workSpaceId="1" d="M0" fill="#BFBEBE"/>
<path data-workSpaceId="2" d="M15.75" fill="white"/>
<path data-workSpaceId="3" d="M14." fill="#20968F"/>
</svg>
```

How I'm fetching the svg in react -

```
<img src={//The svg imported here} onClick={(e) => console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-workSpaceId')) }}
```

Any help welcomed :)

Comment: img element contents are not interactive so this won't be possible unless you use some other container or have the svg inline in the page. Having the svg inline is much simpler.

Comment: The SVG is fetched from an API, what do you suggest the best way to do this.

Comment: What is it about my first comment that's unclear? I.e. add the SVG inline to the page.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `fetch` to get the SVG and use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to insert the SVG.

For instance, if you have the following `test.svg` file in the `public` folder:

```
<svg width="208" height="94" viewBox="0 0 208 94" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path data-id="1" d="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10" fill="#BFBEBE"/>
    <path data-id="2" d="M 5 5 H 50 V 50 H 5 L 5 5" fill="red"/>
    <path data-id="3" d="M 120 120 H 50 V 50" fill="#20968F"/>
</svg>
```

you can write the following:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

function App() {
    const [svgText, setSvgText] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/test.svg")
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(svgText => setSvgText(svgText))
    }, []);

    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: svgText}}
             onClick={(event) => console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-id'))}>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Note that I simplified `data-workSpaceId` to `data-id`.
If you want to keep `data-workSpaceId`, the JavaScript code should be `event.target.getAttribute('data-workspaceid')`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52967417/11197189) helped me.